# IBM Push : cannot use sendNotificationByDeviceIds in ibmpush.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

i have a application and use the function sendNotificationByDeviceIds  as below:

```
PushNotificationToConsumer: function(req, res) {

        queryCustomer.find({jpay_no : jpay_no}).done(function(customerReturn){
            if(customerReturn.length > 0){
                var device_id = customerReturn[0].attributes.device_id.toString();
                req.ibmpush.sendNotificationByDeviceIds(message, [device_id], null).then(function(response){
                    res.json({success : true, message : 'Send notification to patient with device_id:' +device_id+ ' successful ' });
                },function(err){                      
                    res.json(err);
                });
            }else{

            }
        }, function(err){
            res.json(err);
        })

    }
```

The error message: 
[image]

on app.js: I declared ibmpush = require('ibmpush')

please help to give me your thoughts.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ibmpush` is a deprecated node package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibmpush

> **ATTENTION:** This service is currently deprecated on Bluemix and will be completely removed shortly. Please use the 2nd generation of Bluemix MobileFirst Services.

You can use the current Push Swagger docs to implement the functionality you're looking for (using REST API calls):

https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpush/